# Image of a function is closed

Tags: real-analysis

If we are given that the image of a continuous function is a singleton, how would we show that that the inverse is closed as well?

Comment: You can look at the proof of [Closed Graph Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_graph_theorem)

Answer (score 0):

The inverse image of a close set through a continuous function is a closed set.